# Parcel.js. Error EPERM: operation not permitted, rename Cache

Tags: javascript, build, parceljs

I'm using Parcel.js. When I'm trying to run Parcel and build my project via `yarn parcel ./src/index.html`
the EPERM error happens regarding parcel cache.

The error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 
'E:webproject-landing.parcel-cache65ca36a4b4620013e0950eda4009b3b2.blob.22060.1.6'
 -> 'E:webproject-landing.parcel-cache65ca36a4b4620013e0950eda4009b3b2.blob'
```

**OS**: Windows 10 
**Execution ENV**:  Bash terminal/VSCode terminal

Could someone, please, give to me some advice?
Thanks for any help.

P.S. Also, I don't understand why the Path of the project, etc. is so strange, without any separators.  Is this the Parcel specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it, I uninstall parcel, npm uninstall pacel, then installed it again, npm install parcel-bundler --save-dev

Comment: Thank you @Dindowitz, it was working for me as well

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**
Ctrl-C or cancel the server you might have running and restart the dev. server and see if it fixes itself. It did for me.

Not sure if this is still an issue or if anyone else finds themselves here, but Parcel 2 is currently being developed and known bugs are at the github repo and there's a docs/blog for the project both linked below! It has been helping me a bunch!

https://v2.parceljs.org/
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel

Answer (score 1):

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest --force

This works for me!